# Why lost + found directory inside OpenEBS volume?

Tags: kubernetes, iscsi, openebs

Every time when I create a new OpenEBS volume, and mounting the same on the host/application there is a lost+found directory created. 
Is there some way to avoid this and what is need of this?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but the reason is because every ext2/3/4 filesystem has this directory. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lost+found directory is created by ext4.

It can be deleted manually, but will get created on the next mount/fsck. In your application yaml,use the following parameter to ignore this:

```
 image: <image_name>
          args:
            - "--ignore-db-dir"
            - "lost+found"
```

Comment: Do you assume MySQL container? If so, the `ignore-db-dir` option that you've mentioned was removed as of MySQL 8.0

Comment: if we are using own docker and not using mysql container this arg will work ?

Comment: Thanks. Without this parameter, my pod (MySQL 5.7) would always crash with the error message "–initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting."